# Benchmark channel creation NextFlow

Tags: benchmarking, nextflow

I am performing a scatter-gather operation on NextFlow.

It looks like the following:

```
reads = PATH+"test_1.fq"
outdir = "results"

split_read_ch = channel.fromFilePairs(reads, checkIfExists: true, flat:true ).splitFastq( by: 10, file:"test_split" )

process Scatter_fastP {
    tag 'Scatter_fastP'
    publishDir outdir

    input:
    tuple val(name), path(reads) from split_read_ch
    
    output:
    file "${reads}.trimmed.fastq" into gather_fatsp_ch

    script:
    """
    fastp -i ${reads} -o ${reads}.trimmed.fastq
    """
}


gather_fatsp_ch.collectFile().view().println{ it.text }
```

I run this code with all the benchmarks options proposed by Nextflow (https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/tracing.html):
`nextflow run main.nf -with-report nextflow_report -with-trace nextflow_trace -with-timeline nextflow_timeline -with-dag nextflow_dag.html`

In these tracing files, I can find the resources and speed of the 10 Scatter_fastP processes.
But I would like to also measure the resources and speed of the creation of the `split_read_ch` and the `gather_fastp_ch` channels.

I have tried to include the channels' creation in processes but I cannot find a solution to make it work.
Is there a way to include the channel creation into the tracing files? Or is there a way I have not found to create these channels into processes?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Nextflow can parse FASTQ files and split them into smaller files etc, generally it's better to pass off these operations to another process or set of processes, especially if your input FASTQ files are large. This is beneficial in two ways: (1) your main nextflow process doesn't need to work as hard, and (2) you get granular task process stats in your nextflow reports.

The following example uses GNU split to split the input FASTQ files, and gathers the outputs using the [groupTuple()](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#grouptuple) operator and the `groupKey()` built-in to stream the collected values as soon as possible. You'll need to adapt for your non-gzipped inputs:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.num_lines = 40000
params.suffix_length = 5

process split_fastq {

    input:
    tuple val(name), path(fastq)

    output:
    tuple val(name), path("${name}-${/[0-9]/*params.suffix_length}.fastq.gz")

    shell:
    '''
    zcat "!{fastq}" | split \\
        -a "!{params.suffix_length}" \\
        -d \\
        -l "!{params.num_lines}" \\
        --filter='gzip > ${FILE}.fastq.gz' \\
        - \\
        "!{name}-"
    '''
}

process fastp {

    input:
    tuple val(name), path(fastq)

    output:
    tuple val(name), path("${fastq.getBaseName(2)}.trimmed.fastq.gz")

    """
    fastp -i "${fastq}" -o "${fastq.getBaseName(2)}.trimmed.fastq.gz"
    """
}

workflow {

    Channel.fromFilePairs( './data/*.fastq.gz', size: 1 ) \
        | split_fastq \
        | map { name, fastq -> tuple( groupKey(name, fastq.size()), fastq ) } \
        | transpose() \
        | fastp \
        | groupTuple() \
        | map { key, fastqs -> tuple( key.toString(), fastqs ) } \
        | view()
}
```

Comment: First, thank you very much for your detail explanation. It is very useful for my work. Concerning the gather operation I am trying to create, do you know a nice function to implement it in bash? I am looking for a way to write one file from several writers that would work in parallel through a NextFlow process.

Comment: No worries @Nine. Are you just trying to gather up the trimmed.fastq.gz files? If so, all you'd need is: `cat *.trimmed.fastq.gz > sample.trimmed.fastq.gz`. I suspect what you actually need is more complicated though. Can you describe your downstream process(es)?

Comment: yes it is indeed the goal. I can use `cat` in a process to complete this objective. But
I am looking for a way to parallelize this process according to this definition of gather: "A single file is written by multiple compute nodes where each node writes to a disjoint region of the file."
My apologize, it was not obvious and I should have precised it in the definition of my problem.

Comment: No worries at all @Nine. I think having multiple process writing to disjoint regions of a file should be possible using Nextflow, but I think you'd need to specify an absolute path to your output file. This is usually best avoided because once you start using absolute paths, basically you start to sacrifice portability. For example, now you will need to make sure each of your writer processes can write to a shared filesystem.